# Como cambiar el campo estado de una foranea cada 3 meses y mandar un alert

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, date

No tengo idea de como hacer esto. Tengo una vista con dos tabla, donde una me muestra el estado de un equipo y la otra lo mantenimientos que se les hace, lo que quiero hacer es cambiar el estado de "pendiente" a realizado cuando se haga el mantenimiento y cada 3 meses se cambie solo para pendiente y mande un alert diciendo que hay que hacer el mantenimiento. Espero me puedan colaborar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel-heading" align="center"><h2 class="page-header" align="center">MANTENIMIENTO</h2></div>            
    <div class="panel-body">                                    
        <a href="{{route('mantenimiento_imp.create') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-block"  >Nuevo Mantenimiento</a>
    </div>              
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID PC</th>
                <th>Motivo</th>
                <th>Diagnostico</th>
                <th>Ver</th>
                <th>Editar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>               
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if($mantenimientos_imp->count())
            @foreach($mantenimientos_imp as $mantenimiento_imp)  
            <tr>
                <td>{{$mantenimiento_imp->impresora_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$mantenimiento_imp->motivo}}</td>
                <td>{{$mantenimiento_imp->diagnostico}}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="{{route ('mantenimiento_imp.show',  $mantenimiento_imp->id)}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{action('Mantenimiento_impController@edit', $mantenimiento_imp->id)}}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{action('Mantenimiento_impController@destroy', $mantenimiento_imp->id)}}" method="post">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">

                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Esta seguro de Eliminar el Registro?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>       
    </table>

</div>
<?php
$mes = substr($mantenimientos_imp->fecha_mant, 3, 1);
$dia = substr($mantenimientos_imp->fecha_mant, 1, 1);

$f = date("d-m-Y");

$mes_act = substr($f, 2, 2);

$ret = DB::table('mantenimientos_imp')->select('fecha_mant')
        ->where($mes, '<', (int) $mes + 3);
if ($ret != NULL) {
    echo "Hagale mantenimiento";
} else {
    echo "estamos bien";
}
?>
<div class="panel-heading" align="center"><h2 class="page-header" align="center">Impresoras pendiente de Mantenimiento</h2></div>  
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Estado</th>

        </tr>               
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($impresora as $impresoras)  
        <tr>
            @if($impresoras->estado == 'Pendiente')
            <td>{{$impresoras->nombre_imp}}</td>

            <td>{{$impresoras->marca_imp}}</td>

            <td class="label-danger">{{ $impresoras->estado}}</td>
            @endif
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>           
</table>
```

Comment: Esto deberia hacerlo alguna clase de job en la base de datos.. o un proceso automatico del sistema operativo que dispare algo...

Comment: que pasaria si el usuario no entra a la pagina en los proximos 6 meses? como controlarias eso

Comment: Me sumo a @gbianchi lo mejor una tarea automática del sistema ¿que operativo tienes en el servidor? Tu realizas toda la programación en php y que se ejecute automáticamente en la fecha prevista. Adicionalmente puedes poner un botón que ejecute la misma tarea, por si quieres ejecutarlo de forma arbitraria.

Comment: Ya que estas utilizando Laravel, puedes revisar https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling que esta pensado para estas cosas, que agregando un unico cronjob te permite programas las tareas que necesites desde el framework.

Comment: Pero como hago para cambiar el estado cuando se hace el mantenimiento? @gbianchi

Comment: el problema es que no se como hacer la logica para que lo mande cada tres mes, cuando yo ingrese la fecha de mantenimiento se debe dispara a los tres meses y así sucesivamente. @JackNavaRow

Comment: como dice @gbianchi, tu mejor opcion seria preguntar como hacer una tarea en laravel y ejecutarla en PHP , es mas sencillo de lo que suena

Comment: Lo típico es:  tienes una tarea programada en el sistema para que lance tu script una vez al día (por ejemplo); el script comprueba si pasó el tiempo previsto desde el ultimo mantenimiento (en tu caso 3 meses) en caso afirmativo muestra el aviso; el botón aceptar del aviso imputa la fecha actual en el campo que se usa para comprobar la fecha. El quid de la cuestión es se verifica todos los días no solo cada tres meses, por tanto puedes variar el comportamiento tanto como quieras.

Comment: muestra un codigo de ejemplo, pero me interesa tambien cambiar el campo esta cuando se hace el mantenimiento @Fly

Comment: Lo siento, pero no puedo dedicarle más tiempo que tú, intenta implementarlo y pregunta dudas concretas. Ánimo.